# The Project cannot be referenced. The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, monogame

I have once made a game in xna, and have converted it to android using monogame using [this](http://www.jmawebtechnologies.com/company-blog/april-2012/porting-an-xna-windows-phone-game-to-android). Now I need to use some classes  from the new project in the old project and am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project) tutorial to reference the old project in the new project. But soon as I have finished doing this I get a warning saying "The Project "****" cannot be referenced. The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family(.NETFramework)"

I know what is causing this, but I am wondering if there is a way around it or if I can use the classes from different projects in another way?

Comment: Usually when you have to share classes but targeting different platforms/frameworks, either you leverage portable-class-libraries (though I'm not sure if they'll work for Xamarin.Android), or you recreate the same project structure and [link files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234) to share the code.

Comment: I already linked all my files from the old project into the new project but I cannot use the namespace from the new project in the linked class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up Just putting all information and data from my XNA Project into my monogame project because monogame supports XNA and Android. This helped.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin has some documentation about the possible [ways to share code between projects](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options).

It's worth reading but essentially boils down to 2 options:

1. [Portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)
2. File linking into each project

There's a discussion on the Xamarin forums [about current issues with Portable Class libraries](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2847/portable-class-libraries-do-not-work).

There's also another [discussion here about a project file hack](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5023/sharing-code-options-project-linker) to recursively share folders in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, it's not yet possible to do this in Xamarin Studio.

I would love to know if you discover a better way to do this. I've been interested in this issue for a while.

Comment: Another thing is, I can only open the monogame project in xamarin. If I try and load the other project or the whole solution, it won't work because I programmed the other project in XNA. I can still edit the game1.cs file using Xamarin because I already linked it with the new project. The problem is that I can't use a monogame namespace in my linked files.

Comment: Which target framework does android use out of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC592384.png)? I don't think any. :/

Comment: Read the link I provided about current issues with Portable Class Libraries. They used to work on Android but seem to be broken at the moment. Perhaps make your issues known on the Xamarin forums so they are aware people want it fixed.

Comment: There is now official support from Xamarin for Portable Class Libraries.. http://blog.xamarin.com/new-docs-for-your-holiday-hacks/