# Access a value from one project in another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I found this web site:
[How to use a Class from one C# project with another C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project)

however, the class that I want to access is the following. I am using the namespace to access the value but does not work. 
Project B

```
namespace Elettric80.LgvManager
{
    class ConveyorStation : MachineStation 
    {
         public ConveyorStation(LGVManager lgvManager, string name, uint depth, 
                                uint width, uint maxLevels)
            : base(lgvManager, name, depth, width, maxLevels)
         {
         }
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to access:
project A

```
using Elettric80.LgvManager;

private ConveyorStation conveyorStation;

txtvalue.text = conveyorStation.value.ToString();
```

thank you

Comment: do you somehow initialize your field conveyorStation in project A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace Elettric80.LgvManager
{
    class ConveyorStation : MachineStation // compiler is assuming you meant internal class
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

You need to make Conveyor station a 'public' class. Leaving it unspecified makes the compiler assume that you meant 'internal' class, which only allows access from within the same assembly. Change it to:

```
namespace Elettric80.LgvManager
{
    public class ConveyorStation : MachineStation 
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

and your problem should be solved.

---

More completely; the different levels of access levels can be found [here (MSDN - Accessibility Levels).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The relevant quote for this problem:

> Top-level types, which are not nested in other types, can only have internal or public accessibility. The default accessibility for these types is internal.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the access modifier of the `ConveyorStation` class to `public` since by default the access modifier is `internal` (Not accessible from other assemblies).

Additionally, **Make sure you have project reference:**

Right click on project references and add reference to the project that has the value you want to access to.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l5p4.png]