# How can I access expression blend project from a wfa?

Tags: c#, expression-blend

I have a project with some classes. I wanted to change one's(classA) design so I created a new project in expression blend 4. I want to use this in order to do this I need to access that project from main project.

I have in that class:

```
       class1 c = new class1();
       c.pass = read.Value;
       if (c.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
       read.Close();
       return c.status;
       }
```

I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3556586/2763129 but it doesn't work. Is it even possible?

ClassA

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

     namespace momo
   {
       public partial class ClassA : Form
      {
          public string pass;
          public bool status;
          public ClassA()
       {
        status = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Equals(pass))
        {
            status = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errör", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            status = false;
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

my wpf which I try to ipmlement

```
               using System;
              using System.Windows.Data;
       using System.Windows.Documents;
         using System.Windows.Input;
         using System.Windows.Media;
         using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
         using System.Windows.Shapes;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.ComponentModel;
         using System.Data;
         using System.Text;
         using System.Windows;
         using System.Windows.Controls;
         //using System.Windows.Forms;

       namespace ZGNH
       {

public class ayat 
{
    //public checkpassword()
    //{
    //    status = false;
    //    this.InitializeComponent();
    //}

    public string pass;
    public bool status;


}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ayat saf = new ayat();

    string pass;
    bool status;

   //public string pass;
    //public bool status;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //InitializeCo
        this.InitializeComponent();

       // saf.pass = pass;
        //saf.status = status;
        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        //
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        //pass="c";
        //password
        if (pboxxx.Password.Equals(pass))
        {
            status = true;
            //PasswordBox s =new PasswordBox();

            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Window1 s = new Window1();
            s.ShowDialog();
            //MessageBox.Show("Errör", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            status = false;
        }


    }


}
```

}

edit : I tried adding this to mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
        public void show()
     {
        Window.Show();
     }
```

but it gives                                                                                                  The type or namespace name 'MainWindow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  .Visual Studio 2012\Projects\momolocker\momo\memoform.cs    14  7   Momo

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very helpful description of a problem.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn the class that I try to change has two variable which string pass and bool status. I need to access them and showdialog mothod(which I'm not sure there is. because it is not using  System.Windows.Forms); that project http://i.imgur.com/TA25Kcl.png

Comment: And...? Do you expect people to guess what your code looks like? Are you trying to access these variables in a new instance of your class when you really want to be using a existing instance of your class?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn I'm sure it isnt important and relevant. But edited the question if you please check it.

Comment: Probably so. Relevant information is so overrated and unimportant. It will probably be unanswered because you have yet to describe any kind of a problem, other than "it doesn't work". Good luck.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn  on my main class under main project                     ayat ho = new ayat();
                           ho.pass = read.Value; if (ho.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                           {
                               read.Close();
                               return ho.status;
                           }                                                       is doesnt work