# C# referencing to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This question is an extension of a another SO question here: [How to use a Class from one C# project with another C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project)

The most popular answer describes the process to add a reference to another project in the same solution. On following the steps I am able to get Microsoft's Intellisense suggestions for the changes in the other project, however on compiling I face the following error:

> Error 112 'OtherNamespace.ClassObject' does not contain a definition
>   for 'NewProperty' and no extension method 'NewProperty' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'OtherNamespace.ClassObject' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea what is causing the conflict?

EDIT: Sample code:

```
public class ClassObject
{
    public virtual int ExistingProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int NewProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ClassObject()
    {
    }
}
```

I think it might be due to a different reference being used during compile than at the time of code editing. Because there are some weird issues like, if I change an existing property name all the references to it show errors at compile but the new property just doesn't work.

EDIT2: Adding pictures -

Before Compile:

[image]

After compile:

[image]

`tbl_Scaling_Line` is `ObjectClass`, `SuratJalanCheck` is `NewProperty`

Comment: You're missing a `using` directive if the project reference is there.

Comment: @SonerGönül Good shout, my brain is still in weekend mode :)

Comment: Are the two projects in the same solution or not?

Comment: Does your NewProperty has a public modifier?

Comment: Do you have the source code for ClassObject to look at ? intellisense could mix up. Or, maybe, you are referencing an older version, while intellisense is configured to look at a newer version with NewProperty

Comment: @mattytommo I'm not missing the ```using``` directive.

Comment: @Steve, yes both the projects are in the same solution.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin please look at the source code added.

Comment: @Hanan source code added.

Comment: Does the reference work? No yellow exclamation mark? Do you have any warnings or other errors?

Comment: please add the code that calls it

Comment: Please do a BUILD->Clean Solution and then BUILD-> Rebuild Solution. If, for some reason, your projects are not compiled in the correct order you could find yourself stuck in this situation

Comment: @Steve I tried cleaning the solution with no luck. And I had also checked the order of compiling which is proper i.e. compiling the dependencies before the dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as apparent, was due to incorrect references to an older version of the DLL (result of the second project) even though the inter-project references had been set up correctly.

Previously, due to another compile time issue, I had set the build output directory of all projects to the same (as the main project which was using all the DLLs). As it turns out, this was the culprit and was fixed easily by returning each project to it's own build directory and letting the inter-project references do their job.

PS. This question and answer may not be relevant to everyone but I feel it still does provide value to the SO community.