# Open another Project C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a Solution that has a windows forms project in it. I have added a Word Document to it so that I could use this for a reporting tool. It seems that I have run into some problems while trying to open this.

[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project), which helped me out a lot but now when I try to use the code below, I'm getting an error message that tells me "ThisDocument does not contain a constructor that take 0 arguments."

```
        wrd.Application wrdApp = new wrd.Application();
        ThisDocument doc = new ThisDocument();
```

So I look at the tool tips and they say "Mircosoft.Office.Tools.Word.Factory, IServiceProvider". Can someone explain what these are?

Comment: According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189914%28v=office.10%29.aspx) that class is deprecated, consider trying a more up-to-date word interop.

Comment: Bradley, your link is to the Visio ThisDocument object, not the Word interop version.

Comment: How would I reference this to open it then?

Comment: You should not have a reference to Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word, that is only appropriate when you write an add-in for Word.  Did you use the wrong project template?

Comment: I Chose Word 2013 Document. this isn't an add-in.

Comment: ThisDocument refers to the current document.  It isn't used as a constructor but is used instead of an explicitly declared Document object, as explained in this MSDN page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192495%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: thank you for this, bit it seems that I still cannot get this to open. So lets say this document, is Named wrd1 How can I open it?