# creating a new class and calling it from another class c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, data-binding

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming and I'm just interested in starting out.
I've created a simple asp web project and have included multiple webpages where i have dropdown lists.

I can create a class that uses a dataset to select project titles from my database, this all works fine.  My question is how can i call this class from a different webpage to bind the data to my dropdown list?

Below is my code to pull the data i need from my database

```
public void cmbProject()
{
    using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ToString()))
    {
        string sql = "select pr.ProjectID, lo.UserName, " +
                     "pr.Title " +
                     "from Project pr " +
                     "inner join ProjectUsers pu on pu.ProjectID = pr.ProjectID " +
                     "inner join Users us on us.UserID = pu.UserID " +
                     "inner join Login lo on lo.UserID = us.UserID " +
                     "where lo.UserName like '%daniel_23%'";
        try
        {
            oConn.Open();
            //fill drop down list with project listings
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, oConn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            oConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a C# Class Library in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project)

Comment: You didn't realise it but your question has already been asked (many times before). You need to wrap your class in a class library (dll) which you then reference and use from your ASP.NET code behind.

Comment: very sorry, new to this site so its taken me a while to figure things out

Comment: No problem. Follow the above link, do a bit of reading around. Don't hesitate to ask another question if you get stuck again.