# TryUpdateMode doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

To my project I add another separate project and added a database as an ADO.net Entity data model. Then I add a class and  I wrote this function:

```
public void updateNote(int id, Guid userid, string message,  bool Flag)
{           
    t_NOTE Note = GetByNoteId(id);
    Note.Description = message;
    Note.Flag = Flag;

    TryUpdateModel(Note);
}
```

But there is error on `TryUpdateModel(Note);`

> The name 'TryUpdateModel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: What does the class using this method look like? Is it inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a compiler error then you haven't properly imported the class that contains the `TryUpdateModel` method. Did you use an import statement? You'll need to make sure the library is on your project's classpath. In Visual Studio you'd click "Add reference" to do that.

edit: See the following link for more details.

[How do I use a C# Class Library in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project)