# How do I use RedditSharp in Visual Studio (2012)?

Tags: c#, api, reddit

I am making a C# Web Form application and I want to use RedditSharp. https://github.com/SirCmpwn/RedditSharp

I've never used an API in C#, this would be my first time using something outside of the C# generics. Could someone help me understand how to import it to use it?

Comment: This seems like a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project

Comment: @beachwood23 that is for a dll reference. If you look at the github and see the source could you then help me?

Comment: Once you have included the reference to his library (and built it for yourself), you can build your program like his [TestRedditProgram file](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/RedditSharp/blob/master/TestRedditSharp/Program.cs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create C# Web Forms project in Visual Studio
2. Download RedditSharp code from Github
3. Compile RedditSharp into DLL (build enclosed solution, grab DLL from the bin/release folder or wherever it builds to)
4. Add a reference from your project to RedditSharp DLL
5. Check examples at https://github.com/SirCmpwn/RedditSharp, add something like that to your code
6. Don't forget to add "using RedditSharp;" to the top of your code file.

Comment: Thank you. Lastly, how do I turn it into a DLL? :P

Comment: Build RedditSharp.sln. Dll will usually be found under bin/release (if you build it in Release) or somewhere else if solution is configured to output dll somewhere else. Check build configuration in RedditSharp solution.

Comment: lastly it looks like RedditSharp uses DLLs itself. Do I need to add these also?

Comment: Yes, you do need to add any dlls that RedditSharp is dependent upon.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do in Visual Studio is to install the nuget package.  Go to Tools...Nuget Package manager... Manage Packages for Solution.  Search for RedditSharp, click install.

Now you can reference it from anywhere in your project by adding:

```
using RedditSharp;
```

This has the added benefit of Visual Studio alerting you to new updates anytime the official RedditSharp project is updated.