# how to view word documents in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word, ms-office

I have this code viewing text file documents how can change it to be able to view word documents instead of txt file

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));
            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
            FlowDocReader.Document = document;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: No,I want open OpenFileDialog and choose the file word document from it ,Like my code but Idon't know convert the code to be able view word document

Comment: Yes, but the method for opening and reading from the Word file is the same.

Comment: yes,I see it  but I want use OpenFileDialog ,Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You can either use classes found in the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.aspx) namespace or another library. I would suggest the [DocX library](http://docx.codeplex.com/). The library is lightweight and most importantly does not require Office Word to be installed.

```
using Novacode;
// ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".doc";
    dlg.Filter = "Word documents|*.doc;*.docx";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;

        var document = DocX.Load(filename);

        string contents = document.Text;

        // Use the file
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank u,but the erroe found     document = DocX.Load(filename);

                                 string contents = document.Text;

Comment: red line under the document and  DocX

Comment: How should I adding the DocX to my project ,please if u can help

Comment: @lena You can follow the instructions on adding a reference to your project [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project), and download the DLL over [HERE](http://docx.codeplex.com/releases/view/134989).

Comment: I adding it but the same problem, and the  " document "in  document = DocX.Load(filename); refer to what ?

Comment: @lena Sorry about that, I forgot to add the type. I edited my post.

Comment: thank u,this solved ,I'm sorry but the  DocX still the red line found under it ! and the DocX add it as reference

Comment: That's because you didn't add `using Novacode;` at the top of your code.

Comment: Sorry,but when I running this code don't have any error but it doesn't show the file word ,why??

Comment: @lena This method absolutely works but to me it sounds like you just want to copypaste the code and have it magically do whatever you want it to do. I added a comment in my answer `// Use the file` which means that you're supposed to add your own functionality there. For example, if you wanted to add the contents to FileNameTextBox, you would do `FileNameTextBox.Text = contents;`

Comment: I want put it in  documentViewer1.Document =contents ,but I have error " contents" is can't convert type string

Comment: @lena Right. I didn't realize you wanted to use DocumentViewer. I'll edit the answer to follow this post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/

Comment: @lena Wait...you've used the example from that website but have edited it so, that it doesn't work. I don't..understand

Comment: thanks, Isee this post before puting my question here ,put this convert to xps ,and I want it only view as word document ,becuse I'm beginner in the document I don't know how can do it

Comment: @lena The tutorial only converts it to XPS so that DocumentViewer can view it.

Comment: How can use it ,can you tell me please,I apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: @lena The tutorial shows everything. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/