# when you create a library, do you need to provide the cs file or dll file is enough

Tags: dll, c#

As title, I would like to make a basic library of math functions but I would like to know if user need my source code (.cs class) or just providing the .dll file and user adding it in references

Comment: it depends if you are writing it as open source.

Comment: @GrantWinney In normal cases, it should be enough but I am asking in advance cases, I wanna be sure that library won't crash under any circumstance

Comment: @DanielA.White, why do you say it depends?

Comment: are you writing an open source project? how are you distributing it? who is your target audience?

Comment: @DanielA.White if code runs ok and It can help people, i can make it become an open source project. I am not sure yet about how to distribute a project and get at least to recover my lunch and dinner during the days I coded the project? Any suggestion about this issue?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez no i don't that is for you to make your call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100592/discussion-between-pablo-gonzalez-and-daniel-a-white).

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you for your comments. I will done my project and then I will think more about it.

Answer (score 2):

The user only needs the Class Library (dll) and can add a reference to it in her own project

[How to use a Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project)

Comment: You can also provide *.pdb file to simplify debuging but it's not a must of course.

Comment: Should supply the corresponding xml file as well to provide VS intellisense.