# How can I add a source file from another project to the current project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, Suppose I am working on a C# project B, which is stored under path `path1`.

I want to use a class in a source file in another C# project D, which is stored under path `path2`.

That source file contains `using` statement for libraries specified with respect to the root directory of project D, which is different if specified with respect to the root directory of project B.

How can I add the source file of project D to project B, so that I can use some class defined in the source file in project B?

Can you give some examples to show how to do that with or without Visual Studio IDE?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project

Comment: Can I only add a DLL but not a .cs source file from project D to project B?

Comment: Yes, only dll, because file itself doesn't have assembly info, just code.

Comment: Do you really want shared source or do you want to use it as a DLL?  Most of the time in C#, you would compile project D into a DLL and reference that in Project B.

Comment: But Project B is compiled to an executable, not a dll.

Comment: There is way... Make project C, and move classes that you want to be public into. Then compile as library, and in both project D and B reference to dll compiled from project C